# Replace div based on selected dropdown using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to replace the languages in my div when I select a country.. Here's what I got so far but is not working

My fiddle is in the comment, i cant seem to past it here

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/03nobchk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes you need to do 1. value should be 1,2,3

```
 <ul class="country-list" id="country-list" onchange="getval(this);">
                <li value="1" class="Germany">Germany</li>
                <li value="2" class="Singapore">Singapore</li>
                <li value="3" class="Philippines">Philippines</li>
            </ul>
```

and

```
$(".country-list li").click(function() {
           $('#country-dropdown').text($(this).text());
           $('#country-dropdown').click();
           console.log(('.d'+$(this).val()));
            $('.lang').hide();
            $('.d'+$(this).val()).show();
       });
```

Comment: one more thing do you have an idea how I can add a flag image of the selected country? the flag should change depending on the country

Comment: same way, create divs for flag images with class name i1,i2, i3 & so on and hide, show visibilty based on country selection.

Comment: I mean I need to show the image of flag next to the country selected after selecting a country. Is this possible? @Narendra